# While loop >1000 times faster than for loop?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, loops

So the question regarding the speed of for loops vs while loops has been asked many times before. The for loop is supposed to be faster. 
However, when I tested it in Python 3.5.1 the results were as follows:

```
timeit.timeit('for i in range(10000): True', number=10000)
>>> 12.697646026868842
timeit.timeit('while i<10000: True; i+=1',setup='i=0', number=10000)
>>> 0.0032265179766799434
```

The while loop runs >3000 times faster than the for loop! I've also tried pre-generating a list for the for loop:

```
timeit.timeit('for i in lis: True',setup='lis = [x for x in range(10000)]', number=10000)
>>> 3.638794646750142
timeit.timeit('while i<10000: True; i+=1',setup='i=0', number=10000)
>>> 0.0032454974941904524
```

Which made the for loop 3 times faster, but the difference is still 3 orders of magnitude.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I can't quite get the scale of time difference you get; creating a `range()` object has a cost, just not that large a cost. Even on Python 2 I can't get it to go all the way to 12.7 seconds.

Comment: Ah, my laptop is just 6 times faster, that's all.

Comment: what python are you running? it this a debug build where differences are bigger?

Comment: @Alex Python 3.5.1. My laptop is slow, so I expect large absolute time. But do you get wildly different relative difference?

Comment: I have the almost same laptop as Martijn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are creating 10k `range()` objects. These take some time to materialise. You then have to create [*iterator objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) for those 10k objects too (for the `for` loop to iterate over the values). Next, the `for` loop uses the iterator protocol by calling the [`__next__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) on the resulting iterator. Those latter two steps also apply to the `for` loop over a list.

But most of all, you are *cheating* on the `while` loop test. The `while` loop only has to run *once*, because you never reset `i` back to `0` (thanks to [Jim Fasarakis Hilliard pointing that out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44777239/100297)). You are in effect running a `while` loop through a total of 19999 comparisons; the first test runs 10k comparisons, the remaining 9999 tests run one comparison. And that comparison is fast:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('while i<10000: True; i+=1',setup='i=0', number=10000)
0.0008302750065922737
>>> (
...     timeit.timeit('while i<10000: True; i+=1', setup='i=0', number=1) +
...     timeit.timeit('10000 < 10000', number=9999)
... )
0.0008467709994874895
```

See how close those numbers are?

My machine is a little faster, so lets create a baseline to compare against; this is using 3.6.1 on a Macbook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) running on OS X 10.12.5. And lets also fix the `while` loop to set `i = 0` in the test, not the setup (which is run just once):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(10000): pass', number=10000)
1.9789885189966299
>>> timeit.timeit('i=0\nwhile i<10000: True; i+=1', number=10000)
5.172155902953818
```

Oops, so a correctly running `while` is actually **slower** here, there goes your premise (and mine!).

I used `pass` to avoid having to answer question about how fast referencing that object is (it's fast but besides the point). My timings are going to be 6x faster than your machine.

If you wanted to explore why the iteration is faster, you could time the various components of the `for` loop in Python, starting with creating the `range()` object:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('range(10000)', number=10000)
0.0036197409499436617
```

So creating 10000 `range()` objects takes more time than running a single `while` loop that iterates 10k times. `range()` objects are more expensive to create than integers.

This does involves a global name lookup, which is slower, you could make it faster by using `setup='_range = range'` then use `_range(1000)`; this shaves of about 1/3rd of the timings.

Next, create an iterator for this; here I'll use a local name for the [`iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter), as the `for` loop doesn't have to do a hash-table lookup and just reaches for the C function instead. Hard-coded references to a memory location in a binary is a lot faster, of course:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('_iter(r)', setup='_iter = iter; r = range(10000)', number=10000)
0.0009729859884828329
```

Fairly fast, but; it takes the same amount of time as your single `while` loop iterating 10k times. So creating iterable objects is cheap. The C implementation is faster still. We haven't iterated yet.

Last, we call `__next__` on the iterator object, 10k times. This is again done in C code, with cached references to internal C implementations, but with a [`functools.partial()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) we can at least *attempt* to get a ball-park figure:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('n()', setup='from functools import partial; i = iter(range(10000)); n = partial(i.__next__)', number=10000) * 10000
7.759470026940107
```

Boy, 10k times 10k calls to `iter(range(1000)).__next__` takes almost 4x more time than the `for` loop managed; this goes to show how efficient the actual C implementation really is.

However, it does illustrate that looping in C code is a lot faster, and this is why the `while` loop is actually slower when executed correctly; summing integers and making boolean comparisons in bytecode takes more time than iterating over `range()` in C code (where the CPU does the incrementing and comparisons directly in CPU registers):

```
>>> (
...     timeit.timeit('9999 + 1', number=10000 ** 2) +
...     timeit.timeit('9999 < 10000', number=10000 ** 2)
... )    
3.695550534990616
```

It is those operations that make the `while` loop about 3 seconds slower.

---

TLDR: You didn't actually test a `while` loop correctly. I should have noticed this earlier too.

Answer (score 3):

You are timing things incorrectly, `setup` is only executed *once* and then the value of `i` is `10000` for *all consequent runs*. See the documentation on [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit):

> Time number executions of the main statement. This executes the `setup` statement once, and then returns the time it takes to execute the main statement a number of times, measured in seconds as a float.

Additionally verify it by printing `i` for each repetition:

```
>>> timeit('print(i)\nwhile i<10000: True; i+=1',setup='i=0', number=5)
0
10000
10000
10000
10000
```

As a result, all consequent runs merely perform a comparison (which is `True`) and finish early.

Time correctly and see how the `for` loop is actually faster:

```
>>> timeit('i=0\nwhile i<10000: True; i+=1', number=10000)
8.416439056396484
>>> timeit('for i in range(10000): True', number=10000)
5.589155912399292
```